# How do I get something like the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS metadata view of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view itself?

Tags: sql-server, tsql, metadata

All columns of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view are listed at [Learn -> SQL -> SQL Server -> COLUMNS (Transact-SQL):](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

[image]

`COLUMN_NAME` is of data type `nvarchar(128)`:

[image]

But there is no more metadata about this column. Which collation does it have?

Where is the documentation for all of the attributes of this column:

- on the Microsoft sites?
- or perhaps in some SQL Server menu itself? I have Server Management Studio. With DBeaver on a MySQL database, you can check the properties of any view or table with a right click so that you can see all of the column attributes. But MS SQL Server does not have this.
- Or how can I ask for the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view? Something like:

  ```
  select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 
  'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' and c.TABLE_NAME = 'COLUMNS'
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### C# in Visual Studio

You can run this C# code for example from Visual Studio with a Visual C# "ConsoleApp (.Net Framework)" project:

[image]

Which gives you a standard empty project code from where you can go on:

[image]

##### SqlDataReader.GetColumnSchema Method

You can open a reader and then get the column schema with `GetColumnSchema()`. Here is a C# example:

```
using var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
using var command =
    new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS", connection);
connection.Open();
using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
foreach (DbColumn column in reader.GetColumnSchema()) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{column.ColumnName} {column.DataTypeName}({column.ColumnSize})");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Prints:

```
TABLE_CATALOG nvarchar(128)
TABLE_SCHEMA nvarchar(128)
TABLE_NAME nvarchar(128)
COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(128)
ORDINAL_POSITION int(4)
COLUMN_DEFAULT nvarchar(4000)
IS_NULLABLE varchar(3)
DATA_TYPE nvarchar(128)
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH int(4)
CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH int(4)
NUMERIC_PRECISION tinyint(1)
NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX smallint(2)
NUMERIC_SCALE int(4)
DATETIME_PRECISION smallint(2)
CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG nvarchar(128)
CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA nvarchar(128)
CHARACTER_SET_NAME nvarchar(128)
COLLATION_CATALOG nvarchar(128)
COLLATION_SCHEMA nvarchar(128)
COLLATION_NAME nvarchar(128)
DOMAIN_CATALOG nvarchar(128)
DOMAIN_SCHEMA nvarchar(128)
DOMAIN_NAME nvarchar(128)
```

##### SqlConnection.GetSchema Method

Here is now some code from the questioner for an older setup with `SqlConnection.GetSchema()`, done with the help of [SqlConnection.GetSchema Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp_metadata_of_information_schema_test
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string _connectionString => @"Server=mydomain\myservername;Data Source=mydatabase;Initial Catalog=mytestcatalog;Integrated Security=SSPI";

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            SqlCommand command = null;
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection() { ConnectionString = _connectionString };
                conn.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS", conn);
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                ShowDataTable(reader.GetSchemaTable(), 20); 
                // Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user. The pressed key is optionally displayed in the console window.
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine("Exiting Main");
            }
        }

        private static void ShowDataTable(DataTable table, Int32 length)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,-" + length + "}", col.ColumnName);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    if (col.DataType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
                        Console.Write("{0,-" + length + ":d}", row[col]);
                    else if (col.DataType.Equals(typeof(Decimal)))
                        Console.Write("{0,-" + length + ":C}", row[col]);
                    else
                        Console.Write("{0,-" + length + "}", row[col]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Out (only first four rows):

```shell
ColumnName          ColumnOrdinal       ColumnSize          NumericPrecision    NumericScale        IsUnique            IsKey               BaseServerName      BaseCatalogName     BaseColumnName      BaseSchemaName      BaseTableName       DataType            AllowDBNull         ProviderType        IsAliased           IsExpression        IsIdentity          IsAutoIncrement     IsRowVersion        IsHidden            IsLong              IsReadOnly          ProviderSpecificDataTypeDataTypeName        XmlSchemaCollectionDatabaseXmlSchemaCollectionOwningSchemaXmlSchemaCollectionNameUdtAssemblyQualifiedNameNonVersionedProviderTypeIsColumnSet
TABLE_CATALOG       0                   128                 255                 255                 False                                                                           TABLE_CATALOG                                               System.String       True                12                                                          False               False               False                                   False               True                System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlStringnvarchar                                                                                            12                  False
TABLE_SCHEMA        1                   128                 255                 255                 False                                                                           TABLE_SCHEMA                                                System.String       True                12                                                          False               False               False                                   False               True                System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlStringnvarchar                                                                                            12                  False
TABLE_NAME          2                   128                 255                 255                 False                                                                           TABLE_NAME                                                  System.String       False               12                                                          False               False               False                                   False               False               System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlStringnvarchar                                                                                            12                  False
COLUMN_NAME         3                   128                 255                 255                 False                                                                           COLUMN_NAME                                                 System.String       True                12                                                          False               False               False                                   False               False               System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlStringnvarchar                                                                                            12                  False
```

##### Mind

- You cannot find collation in the output of the [SqlConnection.GetSchema Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) with its [DataTable Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) as the output.
- And collation is also not in the output of the newer [SqlDataReader.GetColumnSchema Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getcolumnschema?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) with its [DbColumn Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcolumn?view=net-8.0).

#### Check the view in SSMS

You can also find the INFORMATION view itself under *Views > System Views* in SSMS:
[image]

Comment: I guess this is C# code that you put in SqlDataReader, for example like at [Read data from SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018114/read-data-from-sqldatareader)? Or which reader shall I take to test this? For `COLUMN_NAME`, I try to also get the collation name, not just the data type, that is why I want to run this now.

Comment: Beginner question: How do I get to a data reader quickly, is there any way from inside SSMS? :) You do not need to answer that, I should find it out myself, but perhaps it does not bother you too much.

Comment: `command.ExecuteReader();` creates the reader for you. I had to install the System.Data.SqlClient package in my net8.0 Console application. `DbColumn column` has more properties returning useful information.

Comment: I see, you are on another IDE then, as in the link above, the `.NET` SqlDataReader. I try to avoid installing a new IDE for this. I will try it from inside SSMS with [How do I call C# code from T-SQL, SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71340886/how-do-i-call-c-sharp-code-from-t-sql-sql-server).

Comment: Btw., I was using Visual Studio, I am not familiar with coding in C# inside SSMS.

Comment: Then I will take Visual Studio as well. The last link I posted needs a new assembler in the programmability set, and at first reading, I guess VS is now the quicker way to go.

Comment: I tried to get this to run but I failed since I have .NET `4.6.1` and System.Data.SqlClient `v4.6.1` and this `GetColumnSchema()` function needs  System.Data.SqlClient `v4.8.6`. I then updated it to that version, but it still does not know the method. See also [Usage of SqlDataReader.GetColumnSchema() not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78110309/11154841).

Comment: I guess that my whole setup is so outdated that I cannot run the method, and I should change to net8.0 like you have it. But I guess I cannot do that since I have just VS 2017. I read that from [The type or namespace name 'SQLConnection' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48930113/11154841): "Make sure it is compatible with the type of project (Core/Standard)".

Comment: In old Framework there is also the [SqlConnection.GetSchema Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?view=netframework-3.5&devlangs=csharp).

Comment: This worked, yet, there is no `collation` collumn in the output. Without this, it is not "the same" as the "`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`" since that table has the collation in it. The other answer shows it, but then it does not have the data type. The true data type is `sysname`, which is not in the output here, though `nvarchar(128)` is true as well. The second code block at least shows that it is of DataType `System.String`, which is a good hint at `sysname`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got what you're looking for by going to the native mssql DMVs. Note - I had to use the "all_" versions of them (which include system objects); I *think* this is why information_schema.columns isn't showing up in your original query:

```sql
select c.*
from sys.all_columns as c
join sys.all_objects as o
    on o.object_id = c.object_id
where o.schema_id = schema_id('INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
    and o.name = 'COLUMNS';
```

Comment: This shows me the needed `collation_name: Latin1_General_CI_AS`, but it does not have the `nvarchar(128)` for the data type which I get from the other answer by just showing the columns tree in SSMS. Both together are a good workaround if you do not want to set up a C# query.

Comment: If you need type name, add `type_name(c.system_type_id)` to the list of columns being returned.

Comment: That works, but it returns only the `type_name`. I get `nvarchar` as `type_name`, but I need something like `nvarchar(128)` since I know that this is the true type, see the other answer. Where can I get the `128` from?

Comment: The `max_length` column from sys.all_columns tells you the size in bytes. You're going to have to do some fancy case statements based on the DT to coerce that into what you're looking for. That is, I'd expect a column whose DT is `nvarchar(128)` to show 256 in that column in the query results since nvarchar is two bytes per character.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of some more ways to get the column property information. The other answers and this one together can build a sort of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. The first three headings below have what is needed, the stored procedures show both data type and collation, which the other answers to this question do not have in one go.

Yet, the other C# answer can take up all of this and mix it into one output. It is therefore the only way that can put the whole output together such that the full `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is reached. That is why the C# answer is still the accepted answer even though the built-in stored procedures (`exec sp_hepl`, `exec sp_columns`, `exec sp_describe_first_result_set`) of the first three headings should be the core of the output.

##### exec sp_help 'YOURTABLENAME'

See [SQL statement to get column type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32474909/11154841), the answer with "exec sp_help YOURTABLENAME", please look this up for voting.

[image]

```
exec sp_help 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'
```

Output columns:

> Column_name   Type    Computed    Length  Prec    Scale   Nullable    TrimTrailingBlanks  FixedLenNullInSource    Collation

Output:

```shell
Name                                                                                                                             Owner                                                                                                                            Type                            Created_datetime
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------- -----------------------
COLUMNS                                                                                                                          INFORMATION_SCHEMA                                                                                                               view                            2016-04-30 00:45:03.617

 
 
Column_name                                                                                                                      Type                                                                                                                             Computed                            Length      Prec  Scale Nullable                            TrimTrailingBlanks                  FixedLenNullInSource                Collation
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------- ----- ----- ----------------------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
... (cut) ...
COLUMN_NAME                                                                                                                      sysname                                                                                                                          no                                  256                     yes                                 (n/a)                               (n/a)                               Latin1_General_CI_AS
 
Identity                                                                                                                         Seed                                    Increment                               Not For Replication
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- -------------------
No identity column defined.                                                                                                      NULL                                    NULL                                    NULL

 
RowGuidCol
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No rowguidcol column defined.

 
No constraints are defined on object 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS', or you do not have permissions.
 
No foreign keys reference table 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS', or you do not have permissions on referencing tables.
The object 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS' does not have any indexes, or you do not have permissions.
```

Thus, this shows the data type and the collation in one go, which is near to the whole `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

##### exec sp_describe_first_result_set

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 'select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS';
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set @query, null, 0;
```

Output columns:

> is_hidden column_ordinal name                                                                                                                             is_nullable system_type_id system_type_name                                                                                                                 max_length precision scale collation_name                                                                                                                   user_type_id user_type_database                                                                                                               user_type_schema                                                                                                                 user_type_name                                                                                                                   assembly_qualified_type_name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     xml_collection_id xml_collection_database                                                                                                          xml_collection_schema                                                                                                            xml_collection_name                                                                                                              is_xml_document is_case_sensitive is_fixed_length_clr_type source_server                                                                                                                    source_database                                                                                                                  source_schema                                                                                                                    source_table                                                                                                                     source_column                                                                                                                    is_identity_column is_part_of_unique_key is_updateable is_computed_column is_sparse_column_set ordinal_in_order_by_list order_by_is_descending order_by_list_length tds_type_id tds_length  tds_collation_id tds_collation_sort_id

Output:

[image]

```shell
is_hidden column_ordinal name                                                                                                                             is_nullable system_type_id system_type_name                                                                                                                 max_length precision scale collation_name                                                                                                                   user_type_id user_type_database                                                                                                               user_type_schema                                                                                                                 user_type_name                                                                                                                   assembly_qualified_type_name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     xml_collection_id xml_collection_database                                                                                                          xml_collection_schema                                                                                                            xml_collection_name                                                                                                              is_xml_document is_case_sensitive is_fixed_length_clr_type source_server                                                                                                                    source_database                                                                                                                  source_schema                                                                                                                    source_table                                                                                                                     source_column                                                                                                                    is_identity_column is_part_of_unique_key is_updateable is_computed_column is_sparse_column_set ordinal_in_order_by_list order_by_is_descending order_by_list_length tds_type_id tds_length  tds_collation_id tds_collation_sort_id
--------- -------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- --------- ----- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ----------------- ------------------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------ --------------------- ------------- ------------------ -------------------- ------------------------ ---------------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ---------------- ---------------------
... (cut) ...
0         4              COLUMN_NAME                                                                                                                      1           231            nvarchar(128)                                                                                                                    256        0         0     Latin1_General_CI_AS                                                                                                             256          testDB                                                                                                                           sys                                                                                                                              sysname                                                                                                                          NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL              NULL                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                             0               0                 0                        NULL                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                             0                  NULL                  1             0                  0                    NULL                     NULL                   NULL                 231         256         13632521         0
... (cut) ...

(23 rows affected)
```

##### exec sp_columns

```
exec sp_columns 'COLUMNS', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
```

For more parameters, check the SSMS hint while typing:

[image]

Output columns:

> TABLE_QUALIFIER   TABLE_OWNER TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE   TYPE_NAME   PRECISION   LENGTH  SCALE   RADIX   NULLABLE    REMARKS COLUMN_DEF  SQL_DATA_TYPE   SQL_DATETIME_SUB    CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH   ORDINAL_POSITION    IS_NULLABLE SS_DATA_TYPE

Output:

[image]

```
TABLE_QUALIFIER                                                                                                                  TABLE_OWNER                                                                                                                      TABLE_NAME                                                                                                                       COLUMN_NAME                                                                                                                      DATA_TYPE TYPE_NAME                                                                                                                        PRECISION   LENGTH      SCALE  RADIX  NULLABLE REMARKS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        COLUMN_DEF                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       SQL_DATA_TYPE SQL_DATETIME_SUB CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH ORDINAL_POSITION IS_NULLABLE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    SS_DATA_TYPE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ------ ------ -------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ---------------- ----------------- ---------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------
... (cut)...
testDB                                                                                                                           INFORMATION_SCHEMA                                                                                                               COLUMNS                                                                                                                          COLUMN_NAME                                                                                                                      -9        sysname                                                                                                                          128         256         NULL   NULL   1        NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             -9            NULL             256               4                YES                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            39
... (cut)...

(23 rows affected)
```

##### Make the view a table and check the "Column Properties"

From [Determining Nvarchar length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63624498/11154841) I got the hint of creating a table from the view so that I can check its column property 'Data Type'. I check only the `COLUMN_NAME` column since I need just that, but it stands for any other column, see [Create Table from View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6694515/11154841):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME into dbo.INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS_test from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
```

Then right click on the new table, script table as, create to, new query window:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS_test](
    [COLUMN_NAME] [sysname] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

So we see that it has data type `sysname`.

With another right click on the table, you can also get more properties:

[image]

**(General):**

- (Name): COLUMN_NAME
- Allow Nulls: Yes
- Data Type: sysname
- Default Value or Binding: --

**Table Designer:**

- Collation: <database default>
- Computed Column Specification: --
- Condensed Data Type: sysname
- Description: --
- Deterministic: Yes
- DTS-published: No
- Full-text Specification: No
- Has Non-SQL Server Subscriber: No
- Identity Specification: No
- Indexable: Yes
- Is Columnset: No
- Is Sparse: No
- Merge-published: No
- Not For Replication: No
- Replicated: No
- RowGuid: No
- Size: 128

Thus, the data type is "sysname". The size is `128`, that is, the "string length in byte-pairs", not the number of characters, see the above link again at [Determining Nvarchar length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62820793/11154841).

##### MS SQL Server data type `sysname`

What is this data type `sysname`? See the Microsoft guide [Learn - SQL - SQL Server - nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks):

> `sysname` is a system-supplied user-defined data type that is
> functionally equivalent to nvarchar(128), except that it isn't
> nullable. sysname is used to reference database object names.
>
> Objects that use nchar or nvarchar are assigned the default collation
> of the database unless a specific collation is assigned using the
> COLLATE clause.

##### select `COLUMNPROPERTY()` built-in function to get the string length in byte-pairs

You can also get the "string length in byte-pairs" of a column with TSQL, taken from [How to get the size of a varchar[n] field in one SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45869023/11154841):

```
select COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id('information_schema.columns'), 'column_name', 'PRECISION') as string_length_in_byte_pairs;
```

Out:

```
string_length_in_byte_pairs
128
```

For more on `COLUMNPROPERTY`, see [Microsoft - Learn - SQL - SQL Server - COLUMNPROPERTY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columnproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). But I checked it, it does not have the data type or the collation, only the precision is helpful.

##### select `SERVERPROPERTY()` function to get the server's default collation

And to get the default collation of the db, see [Microsoft - Learn - SQL - SQL Server
View Collation Information - Using Transact-SQL to view the collation setting of a server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/view-collation-information?view=sql-server-ver16#TsqlProcedure):

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar(256), SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));
```

Out:

```
(No column name)
Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Thus, `COLUMN_NAME` is of data type `sysname` (= `nvarchar(128)`) and of collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.